# 'NoneType' object has no attributee 'encoding'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

I am having a prom trying to create and `exe` file from `py` file. I'm using pyinstaller to create the exe file with the parameters `--onefile --noconsole`.

Error:
[image: The error]

this is the message on the terminal during the build

```
255 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.3.0
255 INFO: Python: 3.10.11
262 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22635-SP0
262 INFO: wrote D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\Detect.spec
265 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2']
4598 INFO: checking Analysis
4599 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
4599 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
4600 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
4614 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5200 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5251 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
6257 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7134 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
7226 INFO: Running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7226 INFO: Looking for Python shared library...
7233 INFO: Using Python shared library: C:\Users\Sahayog\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.dll
7233 INFO: Analyzing D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\Detect.py
7276 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7397 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
7574 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
8660 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_pyinstaller'...
9071 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9404 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-platform.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9438 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
9803 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-psutil.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
11074 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torch.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
64065 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'torch.utils.tensorboard' because importing 'torch.utils.tensorboard' raised: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorboard'
[2024-01-18 03:26:43,591] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.redirects: [WARNING] NOTE: Redirects are currently not supported in Windows or MacOs.
84927 INFO: hook-torch: raising recursion limit to 5000
84964 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
85016 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
86686 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sympy.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
87502 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
87978 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook gi from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-gi.py'.
88098 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
88166 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
88802 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
89286 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
90714 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
91557 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
91745 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
97474 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
97938 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
98002 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
99404 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
102815 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
105252 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
107296 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
108297 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
111067 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
112085 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
113063 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
118580 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torchvision.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
118677 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torchvision.io.image.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
119283 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
119609 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torchaudio.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
127016 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
129601 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
130836 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook distutils from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-distutils.py'.
130837 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
131138 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
131178 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
131933 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
137390 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook tensorflow from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-tensorflow.py'.
137940 INFO: Processing module hooks...
143458 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
143459 INFO: Matplotlib backend selection method: automatic discovery of used backends
143471 INFO: Discovered Matplotlib backend(s) via `matplotlib.use()` call in module 'sympy.testing.runtests': ['Agg', 'Agg']
143533 INFO: The following Matplotlib backends were discovered by scanning for `matplotlib.use()` calls: ['Agg']. If your backend of choice is not in this list, either add a `matplotlib.use()` call to your code, or configure the backend collection via hook options (see: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks-config.html#matplotlib-hooks).
143533 INFO: Selected matplotlib backends: ['Agg']
143991 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144328 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144328 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144328 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144352 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144755 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools._distutils.command.check.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144871 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
144871 INFO: checking Tree
144871 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
144872 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
144937 INFO: checking Tree
144937 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
144937 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
144946 INFO: checking Tree
144946 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
144946 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
145002 INFO: Performing binary vs. data reclassification (1784 entries)
145610 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
145710 WARNING: Ignoring /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 imported from D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\_inductor\codecache.py - only basenames are supported with ctypes imports!
145764 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
145789 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
145791 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
145795 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
145797 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook _pyi_rth_utils from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py'.
145800 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_pyi_rth_utils.py' from 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
145801 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
145802 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
145805 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
145813 INFO: Including run-time hook 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_setuptools.py'
145969 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py:194: UserWarning: The numpy.array_api submodule is still experimental. See NEP 47.
  __import__(package)
[2024-01-18 03:27:55,180] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.redirects: [WARNING] NOTE: Redirects are currently not supported in Windows or MacOs.
156574 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (AddDllDirectory): ['D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy.libs', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\../../x64/vc14/bin', '
D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib.libs', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotli
b.libs', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\to
rchvision', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchvision', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas.libs', 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\scipy.libs']
156575 INFO: Extra DLL search directories (PATH): ['D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\../../x64/vc14/bin']
160758 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-60.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160759 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160760 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-9.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160760 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-60.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160760 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-57.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160762 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-59.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160763 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-59.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160764 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-8.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160764 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160766 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160766 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-56.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160767 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-7.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\libtorchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160769 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160769 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avdevice-60.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160770 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-9.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160771 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-60.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160772 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-60.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg6.pyd'.
160772 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-59.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160773 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avdevice-59.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160774 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-59.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160774 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-57.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160775 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-8.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg5.pyd'.
160776 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avcodec-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160776 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avutil-56.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160777 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avformat-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160778 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avdevice-58.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
160778 WARNING: Library not found: could not resolve 'avfilter-7.dll', dependency of 'D:\\PythonProjects\\FruitDetectv2\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages\\torchaudio\\lib\\_torchaudio_ffmpeg4.pyd'.
161165 INFO: Warnings written to D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\build\Detect\warn-Detect.txt
161708 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\build\Detect\xref-Detect.html
161943 INFO: checking PYZ
161943 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
161944 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\build\Detect\PYZ-00.pyz
166649 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\build\Detect\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
166816 INFO: checking PKG
166817 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
166817 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Detect.pkg
595554 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) Detect.pkg completed successfully.
595630 INFO: Bootloader D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\.venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\runw.exe
595630 INFO: checking EXE
595630 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
595630 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
595631 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to D:\PythonProjects\FruitDetectv2\dist\Detect.exe
595634 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
595636 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
595636 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
595637 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
598075 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
608638 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

and this is the code i'm trying to build

```
# Import Libraries
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import math
import cvzone
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.title("Fruit Detection")

    main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#020f12')
    main_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    main_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=5)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    main_frame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)


    def task(button):

        match button:
            case 'button1':
                #root.image = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/desktop", title="Select image to detect")
                cap = cv2.imread("PXL_20240117_233550643.MV.jpg")
                model = YOLO("best.pt")

                classNames = ['Orange', 'Orange', 'Pomegranate', 'Pomegranate', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana',
                              'fruits', 'guava', 'guava', 'guava', 'lime', 'lime']
                while True:
                    success, img = cap.read()
                    results = model(img, stream=True)
                    for r in results:  # data from detect
                        boxes = r.boxes
                        for box in boxes:  # box values
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]  # detection
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)

                            conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100  # confidence
                            print(conf)

                            if conf > 0.75:
                                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 3)  # image, color, thickness
                                cls = int(box.cls[0])  # find what the object is
                                cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'{classNames[cls]}{conf}', (max(0, x1), max(40, y1)), scale=1,
                                                   thickness=1)
                        #img = cv2.resize(img,(1280, 720))
                        img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
                        camera['image'] = img
                        root.update()
                        #cv2.imshow("DetectVideo", img)
                        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
                        print(k)
                    if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                        break

            case 'button2':
                root.video = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/desktop", title="Select video to detect")
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(root.video)

                model = YOLO('best.pt')

                classNames = ['Orange', 'Orange', 'Pomegranate', 'Pomegranate', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana',
                              'fruits', 'guava', 'guava', 'guava', 'lime', 'lime']

                while True:
                    success, img = cap.read()
                    results = model(img, stream=True)
                    for r in results:  # data from detect
                        boxes = r.boxes
                        for box in boxes:  # box values
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]  # detection
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)

                            conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100  # confidence
                            print(conf)

                            if conf > 0.75:
                                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 3)  # image, color, thickness
                                cls = int(box.cls[0])  # find what the object is
                                cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'{classNames[cls]}{conf}', (max(0, x1), max(40, y1)), scale=1, font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,
                                                   thickness=1)
                        #img = cv2.resize(img,(1280, 720))
                        img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
                        camera['image'] = img
                        root.update()
                        #cv2.imshow("DetectVideo", img)
                        '''
                        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
                        print(k)
                    if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                        break
                        '''

            case 'button3':
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
                cap.set(3, 1920)  # width
                cap.set(4, 1080)  # height

                model = YOLO('best.pt')

                classNames = ['Orange', 'Orange', 'Pomegranate', 'Pomegranate', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana',
                              'fruits',
                              'guaba', 'guava', 'guava', 'lime', 'lime']

                while True:
                    success, img = cap.read()
                    results = model(img, stream=True)

                    for r in results:  # data from detect
                        boxes = r.boxes
                        for box in boxes:  # box values
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]  # detection
                            x1, y1, x2, y2 = int(x1), int(y1), int(x2), int(y2)

                            conf = math.ceil((box.conf[0] * 100)) / 100
                            print(conf)

                            if conf > 0.88:
                                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 0), 3)  # image, color, thickness
                                cls = int(box.cls[0])  # find what the object is
                                cvzone.putTextRect(img, f'{classNames[cls]}{conf}', (max(0, x1), max(40, y1)), scale=4,
                                                   thickness=3)
                        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(img))
                        camera['image'] = img
                        root.update()
                        #cv2.imshow("FruitWebcam", img)
                        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
                        print(k)
                    if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
                        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                        break

    frame = LabelFrame(main_frame,width=1920,height=1080,bg='black')
    frame.grid(column=1,rowspan=3)
    camera = Label(frame,bg='black')
    camera.pack()
    #camera = Label(main_frame,width=1280,height=720)
    #camera.grid(column=1,rowspan=3)

    # Define a function to stop the loop
    def on_stop():
        global running
        running = False

    button4 = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Start", command=on_stop)
    button4.grid(column=0,row=4)

    button1 = tk.Button(
        main_frame,
        background='#05d7ff',
        foreground='BLACK',
        activebackground='TEAL',
        activeforeground='BLUE',
        highlightthickness=2,
        highlightbackground='GREY',
        highlightcolor='WHITE',
        width=13,
        height=2,
        text='Image',
        font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'),
        command=lambda: task('button1')
    )
    button1.grid(column=0, row=0)


    button2 = tk.Button(
        main_frame,
        background='#05d7ff',
        foreground='BLACK',
        activebackground='TEAL',
        activeforeground='BLUE',
        highlightthickness=2,
        highlightbackground='GREY',
        highlightcolor='WHITE',
        width=13,
        height=2,
        text='Video',
        font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'),
        command=lambda: task('button2')
    )
    button2.grid(column=0, row=1)

    button3 = tk.Button(
        main_frame,
        background='#05d7ff',
        foreground='BLACK',
        activebackground='TEAL',
        activeforeground='BLUE',
        highlightthickness=2,
        highlightbackground='GREY',
        highlightcolor='WHITE',
        width=13,
        height=2,
        text='Webcam',
        font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'),
        command=lambda: task('button3')
    )
    button3.grid(column=0, row=2)

    root.mainloop()
```

From other forums i have tried with parameter `--noupx` `--windowed` without the two parameters i have included but get the same error

Comment: Please show that error as text, even if that means you have to type it over (and then you'll have to make triply sure you don't introduce typos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libraries like `avcodec-60.dll` and `avutil-58.dll` are missing (needed by `torchaudio`). Thus you'll need to install `ffmpeg`, if it's already installed you could use the `.spec` file to indicate the dll location

```
a = Analysis(['the_python_script.py'],
             ...
             binaries=[('path/to/ffmpeg/dlls/*.dll', '.')],
             ...)
```

Comment: Thanks.. the error is now gone.. but the exe file wont open which seems to be a common issue. I'll look into it now. anyway thanks for solving this one.